# How to find if any element within a list is present within a row in a CSV file when using a for loop

Tags: python, loops, csv, for-loop

```
import csv

with open('example.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvfile = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')

    client_email = ['@example.co.uk', '@moreexamples.com', 'lastexample.com']

    for row in csvfile:
        if row not in client_email:
            print row
```

Assume code is formatted in blocks properly, it's not translating properly when I copy paste. I've created a list of company email domain names (as seen in the example), and I've created a loop to print out every row in my CSV that is not present in the list. Other columns in the CSV file include first name, second name, company name etc. so it is not limited to only emails.

Problem is when Im testing, it is printing off rows with the emails in the list i.e jackson@example.co.uk.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `row` refers to a list of strings. So each row is `['First name', 'Second name', 'Company Name']` etc.

You're currently checking whether any column is exactly one of the elements in your `client_email`.

I suspect you want to check whether the text of any column *contains* one of the elements in `client_email`.

You could use another loop:

```
for row in csvfile:
    for column in row:
        # check if the column contains any of the email domains here
        # if it does:
            print row
            continue
```

To check if a string contains any strings in another list, I often find this approach useful:

```
s = "xxabcxx"
stop_list = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
if any(elem in s for elem in stop_list):
    pass
```

Comment: `any([elem in s for elem in stop_list])` => `any(elem in s for elem in stop_list)` no need to create a list.

Answer (score 0):

One way to check may be to see if `set` of client_email and `set` in row has common elements (*by changing if condition in loop*):

```
import csv

with open('example.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvfile = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')

    client_email = ['@example.co.uk', '@moreexamples.com', 'lastexample.com']

    for row in csvfile:
        if (set(row) & set(client_email)):
            print (row)
```

You can also use `any` as following:

```
import csv

with open('untitled.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvfile = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')

    client_email = ['@example.co.uk', '@moreexamples.com', 'lastexample.com']

    for row in csvfile:
        if any(item in row for item in client_email):
            print (row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way,

```
import csv

data = csv.reader(open('example.csv', 'r'))
emails = {'@example.co.uk', '@moreexamples.com', 'lastexample.com'}
for row in data:
    if any(email in cell for cell in row for email in emails):
        print(row)
```

Comment: `set(emails).intersection(row)` => `not emails.isdisjoint(row)` and make `emails` a `set` else it'll be slow as hell.

Comment: Yeah just checked with basic time test. And yes it'll be slow. (With two strings matching) Using my code - **-0.0025970935821533203** and as you suggested - **-0.00037407875061035156**. Cheers. Will update.

Comment: Yeah sure! @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: err actually I think that won't work because it seems that OP wants to test addresses as _substrings_ of the actual rows; not exact strings.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I have a different solution for this though its slow. Let me update.

Comment: Not too slow though **-0.00030303001403808594**.